Determine which process uses which fields in Azure DevOps
I have an Azure Devops organization that I am trying to clean up after a period of un-administered use. The org has a number of projects using approx. 45 different processes. What I am trying to find is a way to identify which fields (of which I have lots) are being used by which processes or more to the point which fields are now no longer used.
I have tried looking through the APIs and can get a list of fields (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields) and a list of processes (https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.2) but I can't seem to identify the link between identifying which fields are used by which processes.

May i know if you got a chance to check the rest api and script below? It works on my side. Let me know if you have any queries.


What I am trying to find is a way to identify which fields (of which I have lots) are being used by which processes or more to the point which fields are now no longer used.

There is no existing feature and method to achieve this, you could need several rest apis and customized script as below:

List All Fields: You've already got this part covered with the API endpoint https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/wit/fields.

List All Processes: Similarly, you have the endpoint
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.2
to list all processes.

Get Process Work Item Types: For each process, you need to get the work item types. Use the endpoint:


GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2

This will give you the work item types for each process.

Get Work Item Type Fields: For each work item type, get the fields using:

GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/work/processes/{processId}/workItemTypes/{witRefName}/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2

This will list the fields used by each work item type within a process.

Cross-reference Fields: By iterating through the processes and their work item types, you can build a mapping of which fields are used by which processes, and which field are not used in any process.

The PowerShell script below, change the orgname and personal access token(pat) to yours:
# Define variables
$organization = "orgname"
$personalAccessToken = "pat"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))

# Function to make API requests
function Invoke-DevOpsRestMethod {
    param (
        [string]$uri
    )
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers @{
        Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"
        Accept = "application/json"
    }
    return $response
}

# Get all fields
$fieldsUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=6.0"
$fields = Invoke-DevOpsRestMethod -uri $fieldsUri


# Get all processes
$processesUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/work/processes?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
$processes = Invoke-DevOpsRestMethod -uri $processesUri

$fieldUsage = @{}


foreach ($process in $processes.value) {
    $processId = $process.typeId

    # Get work item types for each process
    $witUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/work/processes/$processId/workItemTypes?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
    $workItemTypes = Invoke-DevOpsRestMethod -uri $witUri

    
    foreach ($wit in $workItemTypes.value) {
        $witRefName = $wit.referenceName
        # Get fields for each work item type
        $witFieldsUri = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/_apis/work/processes/$processId/workItemTypes/$witRefName/fields?api-version=6.0-preview.2"
        $witFields = Invoke-DevOpsRestMethod -uri $witFieldsUri

        
        foreach ($field in $witFields.value) {
            $fieldRefName = $field.referenceName
            if (-not $fieldUsage.ContainsKey($fieldRefName)) {
                $fieldUsage[$fieldRefName] = @()
            }
            $fieldUsage[$fieldRefName] += $process.name
        }
    }
}


# Print fields and their usage
foreach ($field in $fieldUsage.Keys) {
    $processList = $fieldUsage[$field] -join ", "
    Write-Host "Field: $field is used in processes: $processList"
}

# Print fields that are not used by any process
$unusedFields = $fields.value | Where-Object { -not $fieldUsage.ContainsKey($_.referenceName) }
foreach ($unusedField in $unusedFields) {
    Write-Host "Field: $($unusedField.referenceName) is not used in any process"
}

The output:

